# Force network messages from VM's on same ESXi to gateway

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

In the context of introducing ESXi we would like to know if it is possible to force messages destined from VM_A to VM_B on the same ESXi towards the gateway. The reason behind this seemingly strange request is that we need to be able to capture them in our respective solution for troubleshooting if there is ever a need for that

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? "Messages"?

Comment: We have one ESXi server hosting VM_A and VM_B. These VM's will have applications that will communicate with each other... We may have to troubleshoot the messages between them thus we need them to leave the ESXi server so that the mirroring port on the physical switch can send their traffic to wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using a "vShpere 5 Distributed Switch." See http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2011/08/vsphere-5-new-networking-features-port-mirroring.html

> Port mirroring provides visibility into
>
> • Intrahost virtual machine traffic (virtual machine–to–virtual
>   machine traffic on the same host)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i believe that this will do the trick...If i understand correctly though i need to have vCenter in order to create a vDS, correct?

Comment: Not sure but it looks like you can do it with esxcli / esxcfg-vswitch directly on the esxi host.